# how to read in indefinite # of input parameters in a function/subroutine in Fortran?

Tags: function, input, fortran, subroutine

The following fortran code will calculate the area of a circle or a rectangle according to user's input. If there is only one input floating point then it will calculate the area of a circle while if there are two then it will return the area of a rectangle. Currently, I do this by user typing 1 or 2 at first. However, I would like to know if there are direct ways of reading in indefinite # of input parameters in fortran. Please do offer your wisdom. I appreciate it!

```
module MA
  implicit none

interface area
  module procedure area_circ  ! calculate the area of circles
  module procedure area_rec   ! rectangles
end interface

contains
  real function area_circ(a)
  implicit none
  real, intent(in) :: a
  real, parameter :: pi=3.14159
  area_circ = pi*a**2
  write(*,"('Area of circle = ',F6.2)") area_circ
  return
end function area_circ

real function area_rec(a,b)
  implicit none
  real, intent(in) :: a,b
  area_rec=a*b
  write(*,"('Area of rectangle = ',F6.2)") area_rec
  return
end function area_rec

end module MA

program hw1101
  use MA
  implicit none
  real :: a,b,S
  integer :: i

  write(*,*) 'Please type # of parameters: '
  read(*,*) i
  if(i==1) then
    write(*,*) "Please type one parameter: "
    read(*,*) a
    S=area(a)
  else if (i==2) then
    write(*,*) "Please type two paramters: "
    read(*,*) a,b
    S=area(a,b)
  else
    write(*,*) "Other functions under construction..."
  end if

  stop
end program hw1101
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An up-to-date Fortran compiler provides a number of intrinsic routines for handling command line arguments.  You can use the function `COMMAND_ARGUMENT_COUNT` to get the number provided when you execute the program, then read them one by one.  Perhaps something like this:

```
  CHARACTER(len=16) :: arg
  REAL, DIMENSION(4) :: arguments
  ...
  DO ix = 1, COMMAND_ARGUMENT_COUNT()
     CALL GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(ix,arg)
     READ(arg,*) arguments(ix)
  END DO
```

Note that the subroutine `GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT` returns a character variable through the second argument (which I've called `arg`).  It has other, optional, arguments so you might want to check some documentation.

There's nothing wrong with your current approach for determining which `area` function to call but if you wanted to you could also write an area function which takes optional arguments.  Here's an example:

```
  REAL FUNCTION area(a,b)
    REAL, INTENT(in) :: a
    REAL, INTENT(in), OPTIONAL :: b
    IF (.NOT.PRESENT(b)) THEN
       area = 3.14159*a*a
    ELSE
       area = a*b
    END IF
  END FUNCTION area
```

which should give you the general idea. The attribute `OPTIONAL` and the intrinsic logical function `PRESENT` are what you need for routines with optional argument.  I think the approach you've already taken is actually better.

Answer (score 0):

```
real a, b, s
character(len=20) :: string_in
integer istat
read(*, '(a)') string_in
read(string_in, *, iostat=istat) a, b
if (istat /= 0) then
    read(string_in, *, iostat=istat) a
    if (istat == 0) s = area (a)
else
    s = area (a, b)
end if
```